# vscode terminal bat files and having code run inside vscode terminal instead of popup terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, visual-studio-code, cmd

I am trying to make a .bat to start up a node app - I want to run this .bat from the terminal of vscode and I want it to execute in that context...

that real challenge I've been facing is how to open up another terminal in the vs code environment, and not a cmd that likes to pop up.

what I used to do to start up the dev server:

```
ctrl+shift+5
cd server
npm run dev
click over to the other window
cd client
npm run dev
```

my end goal is

```
start run.bat
```

my run.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
:_start
ECHO select an environment:
ECHO 1. dev
ECHO 2. Production
ECHO choose by number :
set choice=
set /p choice=">> "
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto _development
if '%choice%'=='2' goto _production
ECHO BAD CHOICE TRY AGAIN
ECHO.
goto _start

:_development
CALL dev.bat /b @dev.bat /k
goto _end
:_production
CALL prod.bat /b @prod.bat /k
goto _end

:_end
pause
```

dev.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO starting development
CD startup scripts
START startDevClient.bat @startDevClient.bat /k /b
CALL startDevServer.bat @startDevServer.bat /k
```

startDevClient

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO opening client
CD ..
CD client
NPM run dev
PAUSE
```

startDevServer

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO opening server
CD ..
CD server
NPM run dev
PAUSE
```

the issues are:

start run.bat opens up a new cmd window, and does not execute inside the vscode enviroment.

the start in the dev.bat calls a cmd window and I have no idea how to specify I want that to open as if I hit ctrl+shift+5 in vscode.

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I want, or close enough.

by using vscode's tasks, I could make a main task that ran two sub-tasks and dictate how they would open in the terminal.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "spin up dev server",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npm run dev",
            "options":{
                "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}/server"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "group":"DEVELOPMENT"
              }
        },
        {
            "label": "spin up dev client",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npm run dev",
            "options":{
                "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}/client"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "group":"DEVELOPMENT"
              }
        },
        {
            "label": "spin up prod server",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npm run prod",
            "options":{
                "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}/server"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "group":"PRODUCTION"
              }
        },
        {
            "label": "spin up prod client",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npm run prod",
            "options":{
                "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}/client"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "group":"PRODUCTION"
              }
        },
        {
            "label": "DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT",
            "dependsOn": ["spin up dev client", "spin up dev server"]
          },
          {
            "label": "PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT",
            "dependsOn": ["spin up prod client", "spin up prod server"]
          }
    ]
}
```